QgsVectorLayer cant open JSON string converted from Pandas dataframe
I am new to PyQGIS and I have a problem where QgsVectorLayer doesnt seem to understan
I am working in processing script to build a model in QGIS. I am running to issue where the result of method cant be open. The result of the last part is a pandas dataframe with no geometry value. I am trying to convert it back to vector layer with no geometry as the output of this model
Here is the snippet of the code
    # in processAlgorithm

         ....

        #type: pandas dataframe with no geometry
        parsed_data_df = self.parse_response_data(response_data) 
        
        if parsed_data_df is not None:
            results['Matrix'] = QgsVectorLayer(parsed_data_df.to_json(),"matrix","ogr")
        return results

Here is the warning after running the model
WARNING    Cannot open {"originIndex":{"0":0,"1":1},"destinationIndex":{"0":0,"1":0},"lengthInMeters":{"0":1008,"1":1198},"travelTimeInSeconds":{"0":174,"1":192}} ().()

I have tried various conversion (to_json, to_csv, to_list) but none of them seem to work. I hope anyone have an idea to solve this problem.

When you provide a JSON string for QgsVectorLayer's first parameter, it must be a GeoJSON string.
You are using a Pandas dataframe. You need to use GeoPandas and your data needs to be spatial data with a geometry column.
Then you can use geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_json to get a GeoJSON string.
